# Is it possible to have two DHCP server on the same LAN/SUBNET?

Tags: dhcp

Is it possible to have two DHCP server on the same LAN/SUBNET? If so, how can you configure it?

I'm doing some research and I'm getting mixed results. In one article, it says "On the same subnet, you absolutely cannot run two DHCP servers that assign addresses from the same range. However, on the same subnet, you can have two DHCP servers that assign addresses from different ranges". Another article says that you can setup DHCP failover.

Can anyone help explain this to me? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Everything in your quoted part is accurate.  You can't have two dhcp servers assigning the same addresses, they won't be in sync.  You can have two dhcp servers assigning different ranges, because they won't care about IP ranges that aren't theirs.  You can just let the one that responds first respond or you can manually configure each dhcp server individually to respond to specific mac addresses.  Failover is something entirely different.  It means there is something configured as a backup if the one active server has a problem.

Comment: You can do that but it's strongly not recommended. Yes, one server can assign like from IP 2 to IP 100 and another from 101 to 199 or so, but what would be the point in making such a mess ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the dhcp server implementation. If there is no communication between the servers then the address pools should not overlap. If there is a communication mechanism, such as [ISC's dhcp server](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01356), then the address pools can overlap.